# Filter elements in a list by length - Ocaml

Tags: random, ocaml

I have the following list:

```
["A";"AA";"ABC";"BCD";"B";"C"]
```

I am randomly extracting an element from the list. But the element I extract should be of size 3 only not lesser than 3.

I am trying to do this as follows:

```
let randomnum = (Random.int(List.length (list)));;
let rec code c =
    if (String.length c) = 3 then c
    else (code ((List.nth (list) (randomnum)))) ;;
print_string (code ( (List.nth (list) (randomnum)))) ;;
```

This works fine if randomly a string of length 3 is picked out from the list.

But the program does not terminate if a string of length < 3 is picked up.
I am trying to do a recursive call so that new code keeps getting picked up till we get one of length = 3.

I am unable to figure out why this is does not terminate. Nothing gets output by the print statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only pick a random number once.  Say you pick 5.  You just keep recursing with 5 over and over and over.  You need to get a new random number.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want to write is

```
 let rec code list =
   let n = Random.int (List.length list) in
   let s = List.nth list in
   if String.length s < 3 then code list else s
```

Note that, depending on the size of the list and the number of strings of size greater than 3, you might want to work directly on a list with only strings greater than 3:

```
let code list =
  let list = List.filter (fun s -> String.length s >= 3) list in
  match list with
  | [] -> raise Not_found
  | _  -> List.nth list (Random.int (List.length list))
```

This second function is better, as it always terminate, especially when there are no strings greater than 3.

Answer (score 1):

For your code to terminate, it would be better to first filter the list for suitable elements, then take your random number:

```
let code list =
   let suitables = List.filter (fun x -> String.length x = 3) list in
   match List.length suitables with
   | 0 -> raise Not_found (* no suitable elements at all! *)
   | len -> List.nth suitables (Random.int len)
```

Otherwise your code would take *very* long to terminate on a large list of elements with size <> 3; or worse on a list with no element of size 3, it would not terminate at all!